# MQTT.js - Uncaught TypeError: n.createConnection is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, mqtt, mqtt.js

I try to connect my webapp with my MQTT-Broker. I decide to use MQTT.js, but there is an error in my code:

```
Uncaught TypeError: n.createConnection is not a function
    at t.exports (mqtt.min.js:1:29576)
    at T.streamBuilder (mqtt.min.js:1:39683)
    at T._setupStream (mqtt.min.js:1:6556)
    at new T (mqtt.min.js:1:5968)
    at Function.u [as connect] (mqtt.min.js:1:39286)
    at (index):23:29
```

The exception will be thrown in line `const client = mqtt.connect(broker);`   .
I don't know, how to solve this issue, I hope you can help me.

Here is a minimal example of my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MQTT Data Display</title>
    <script src="mqtt.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>MQTT Data Display</h1>
    
    <h2>Receiving Data:</h2>
    <textarea id="dataField" rows="5" cols="50" readonly></textarea>
    
    <h2>Input text:</h2>
    <input type="text" id="inputField" />
    <button onclick="publishMessage()">Send</button>
    
    <script>
        // MQTT Broker config
        const broker = 'mqtt:<BrokerURL>';
        const topic = 'your-mqtt-topic';

        // create MQTT Client
        const client = mqtt.connect(broker);

        // connect MQTT Client
        client.on('connect', function () {
            console.log('MQTT connected');
            client.subscribe(topic);
        });

        // Receive new message
        client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
            const data = message.toString();
            const dataField = document.getElementById('dataField');
            dataField.value = data;
        });

        // publish messsage
        function publishMessage() {
            const inputField = document.getElementById('inputField');
            const message = inputField.value;
            client.publish(topic, message);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What version of mqtt.js are you using? You might be using a version that does not support websockets.

Comment: @IanBrindley : Version 4.3.7

Comment: Try 4.0.1, this should support websockets.

Comment: @IanBrindley: Now, I have installed 4.0.1, but there is  a new error: `WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/' failed: `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running from inside a web browser you **MUST** use MQTT over Websockets, you can not use native MQTT because the browser sandbox will not allow you to connect to arbitrary TCP ports.

So you must first have a broker that is configured to accept connections via MQTT over Websockets.

Second you need to change the `broker` variable to be the a URL starting with `ws://` not `mqtt://`

Next, is the browser running on the same machine as the MQTT broker? `localhost` is only going to access the machine the browser is running on which is not normally the case for web pages.

Comment: After I check, if the broker accept websocket requests, I found out that was disable. So I enabled it and now it works. Thank you.